# Populating employee table with multiple rows of data in oracle using pl/sql or other oracle related methods?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created an employee table with 3 columns with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    (Sal number(9,2),
    empID number(7) not null unique,
    depID number (3)
    );
```

I am new to pl sql and oracle in general so I don't know where I am going wrong but  I have tried variations of the below and I keep getting syntax errors:

```
BEGIN
     FOR icount IN 1..5000 LOOP
       INSERT INTO Employee(empID,Sal,depID)
       VALUES (icount, (integer(50000+rand()*70000)),(integer(empID%20))
       );
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

I would prefer that the salary lie between 50,000 to 120,000 
and depID be the anywhere from 1 to 20 which is why I wanted to use modulo operation.

Can you please recommend the best method to populate this table and also tell me where I am going wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank you very much :D

Comment: Perhaps it is the `e` missing on the end of `Employee` and the fact that you reference `empID` in the values statement when you mean `icount`?

Comment: the e at the end was a typo and I changed empID to icount but that didn't really change the errors, I am still getting an error. In the error it says that I am missing an expression and that an sql statement was ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `RAND()` function in Oracle - the closest equivalent is the version of DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE which takes no arguments, but the version which accepts a low and high value and generates a random value between them is nicer to work with in this situation. In Oracle we use the `TRUNC` function to truncate a number, and the `MOD` function should be used to compute remainders.

```
BEGIN
  FOR icount IN 1..5000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO Employee
      (empID,  Sal,                                     depID)
    VALUES
      (icount, TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(50000, 120001)), MOD(icount, 20));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.